# Windows cannot access UNC path (error code 0x80070035)

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-networking, unc

Have a Windows 8.1 PC with a recurring problem when attempting to access a UNC path from a Server 2008 R2 host.

```
Windows cannot access \\SERVER
Error code 0x80070035
The network path was not found.
```

Other computers can access the UNC path ok.

The Windows 8.1 PC can access the path via IP (i.e. \192.168.0.12).

On the Windows 8.1 PC - Windows Firewall is disabled, Webroot anti-virus uninstalled, no Windows Updates to install, services such as DNS Client, Computer Browser, TCP/IP Helper are started.

Comment: Do you have NETBIOS over TCP/IP enabled? And Client for Microsoft Network?

Comment: NETBIOS over TCP/IP was previously set to enabled on the network adapter, and Client for MS Network is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset TCP/IP stack to resolve this issue. After the PC was restarted access was restored immediately.